# Automatically fetch assets from external source

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I have a very basic question to Contentful CMS: Is it possible to configure a job in Contentful that automatically fetches images from external source?

My first guess was webhooks, but I think they are just suitable to notify extern systems of a Contentful event?

Scenario:

- Image on external server that changes day to day (i.e. http://server/changingImage.jpg)

--> Contentful should download and import this image for example every 24 hours and then publish it to be visible for an application.

Is it possible to configure such jobs / scripts within Contentful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Contentful itself, no. We do not have anything pre-built that pulls content like that, and your description of webhooks is correct. That's for events within Contentful.

You should check out the UI extensions: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/uiextensions/

They allow you to build your custom integration points directly in the contentful web interface.

Combined with something like Azure functions or AWS lambda it should be fairly easy to set something up along the lines you describe.